# WCF service operation freeze while in Windows Service

Tags: windows, wcf, service, freeze

I can connect to WCF service but only when I create Client in Console Application. When I create a Windows Service and try to connect with the same client I get timeouts. All addresses are setup in code.

My endpoint looks like this:

```
  <endpoint
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingConfig"
              contract="ServiceInterface" name="BindingName" />
```

And method is invoked like this:

```
 ReturnModel logonResponse = client.Logon(SendModel);
```

Method logon is timing out.

EDIT: I discovered that everything works for console application but not for service under local system privileges. It doesn't work for cross network requests. When I set Windows Service privileges to my account name rather than local system everything works. But it's workaround not solution. Any ideas how to configure it with WCF?

Comment: the windows service is running under which account? admin? network?

Comment: Local system account is checked. 
I don't know which option should be checked to behave exact as my Console Application.

Comment: @Zbigniew Try setting it to **NETWORK SERVICE** first.  If that doesn't work (perhaps due to any authentication model you have not mentioned) to the same account that you use to login to Windows

Comment: with NETWORK SERVICE my windows service can't even register his own WCF service

Comment: Do you have a proxy that is not configured for your service account? i.e. only set the proxy for your local account rather than machine-wide.

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this? Found only complicated solutions.

Comment: I am almost sure it's working. That was golden shot!:)

Answer (score 2):

After hours of research and ta.speoit.is post, solution was to enter flag to ignore proxy.

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding useDefaultWebProxy="false">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```